# ASP.Net MVC Scripts not working with controller's default action url. Same is working with controller/action url

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, url, action

When mvc application is queried with controller name alone in the url without specifying action, the page is rendered but ajax/scripts are not working, whereas the same page when queried with action in the url, is working as expected.

Not working url: http://localhost:port/Search --> Page rendering is fine but scripts are not working - Search results are not showing up

Working url: http://localhost:port/Search/Index --> Page and scripts are working as expected - Search results are showing up

C#:

```
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    private readonly List<string> _cars;
    public SearchController()
    {
        _cars = new List<string>{"Corolla","Camry","Civic","Land Rover","Range Rover","Polo"};
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetMatchingResults(string filter)
    {
        var results = await Task.Run(() => GetSearchResults(filter));
        return new JsonResult() { Data = results,JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
    private List<string> GetSearchResults(string filter)
    {
        var results = _cars.Where(car => car.Contains(filter));
        return results.ToList();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head> 
       @using System.Web.Optimization   
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />    
       <script src="~/Scripts/ApplicationScripts/SearchViewJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <title>SearchView</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <input class="searchText" type="search" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input class="searchResults" type="text" />
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".searchText").on('input', function (event) {
        var filter = $(event.currentTarget).val();
        search(filter).then(display);
    });

    function search(filter) {
        return $.getJSON('GetMatchingResults/', { 'filter': filter });
    }

    function display(result) {
        $(".searchResults").val(result);
    }
})
```

Comment: It needs to be `$.getJSON('/Search/GetMatchingResults', ..` (leading slash). You should always use `'@Url.Action("GetMatchingResults", "YourControllerName")'` to generate the correct url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the context of

```
$.getJSON('GetMatchingResults/', { 'filter': filter });
```

In the first case that will be trying to hit /GetMatchingResults the second tries to hit /search/GetMatchingResults.  A fix could be to use

```
$.getJSON('/search/GetMatchingResults/', { 'filter': filter });
```

Or even better would be to generate the path from a HTML helper that will route correctly if you update your routing rules.  This would look something like

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetMatchingResults", "Search")', { 'filter': filter });
```